# how to mock or unit test the celery task custom update

Tags: python, flask, celery, pytest, celery-task

The celery is used in connexion flask. the celery worker is remote. In celery task has a update the status. How to mock the custom task status in unit test.
celery broker is rabbit mq, celery backend is database sqlite as of now, but will eventually move to postgresql.

```
app_file.py
from .base import database_init, create_db
def create_app(**kwargs):
    """ To setup Flask app """
    connexion_app = create_connexion()
    flask_app = connexion_app.app
    load_config(flask_app)
    database_init(flask_app)
    create_db()
    cache.init_app(flask_app, flask_app.config)
    if kwargs.get('celery'):
        init_celery(kwargs.get('celery'), flask_app)
    init_app(connexion_app)
    CORS(flask_app)
    return flask_app

def create_connexion():
    options = {"swagger_path": "../swagger/dist"}
    connexion_app = connexion.App(
        __name__, specification_dir='swaggers/',
        options=options)
    return connexion_app
app = create_app(celery=celery)
```

The database exists in base.py

```
base.py

from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate


db = SQLAlchemy()


def database_init(application):
    """Initialize the db."""
    # application.app_context().push()
    db.init_app(application)
    Migrate(application, db)


def create_db():
    """just a function which create the database according
    to classes imported"""
    db.create_all()
```

In api layer

```
apis/fs.py
def create_fs_api(data):
    """Creates the fs"""

    tasks = FSService.createFS.apply_async(
        kwargs={'availability_zone': data['availability_zone'], 'description': data['description'],
                'protocol': data['protocol'], 'network': data['network'], 'size': data['size'],
                'user_id': user_id, 'account_id': account_id})
    return jsonify({'jobId': tasks.id}), 201, \
        {'Location': url_for('/fs/v0.apis_Fs_controllers_jobs_get_job_id',
                             job_id=tasks.id, _external=True)}
```

In resource file, in unit test update_state is not able to mock . Here the whole business logic is not given .

```
controllers/Fs_service.py
class FSService:

    @celery.task(bind=True)
    def createFS(self, availability_zone, description, protocol, network, size, user_id, account_id):
        """Creates the fsystem"""
        current = 0
        count = 1
        sleep_time = size

        for i in range(count):
            time.sleep(sleep_time)
            fsId = get_uuid()
            current += 1
            self.update_state(state='PROGRESS',
                              meta={'current': i, 'total': count})
        region = get_region(availability_zone)

        data = {'fs_Id': fsId,
                 'status': 'ready',
                'size': size,
                'created': datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
                'modified': datetime.datetime.utcnow()}
        FOperations.create_fs(data)
        time.sleep(20)
        return {'fsId': [fsId, ], 'count': count, 'status': 'Fs Created Successfully',
                'current': current, 'total': count, 'type': 'Fs'}
```

In conftest.py, how to mock the create_db

```
@pytest.yield_fixture(scope='session')
def flask_app():
    """ Setup Flask app for Testing """
    with patch.object(app_file, 'celery') as celery_mock:
         app = app_file.create_app(celery=celery_mock)
          with app.app_context():
              yield app


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def flask_app_client(flask_app):
    """ Load up Flask app api client for testing """
    flask_app.response_class = JSONResponse
    return flask_app.test_client()
```

In unit test

```
test_fs_service.py

@pytest.mark.celery(result_backend='redis://')
class TestFS:

    def test_createfs(self, mocker):
        uuid = mocker.patch('apis.Fs.resources.fs_service.get_uuid')
        uuid.return_value = 'cf905c4f-122f-4b36-8441-7efff26aa6bf'
        mocker.patch('apis.Fs.resources.fs_service.time.sleep')
        mocker.patch('apis.Fs.resources.fs_service.FOperations.create_fs')
        res = FSService.createFS("us", "fs for clb", "nfsv4", "l1", 3,
                                         '13434', 'fcd4f7f1-7bf2-4409-9a25-de9edf0a7747')
        assert res == {'fSId': ['cf905c4f-122f-4b36-8441-7efff26aa6bf', ], 'count': 1,
                       'status': 'FS Created Successfully', 'current': 1, 'total': 1, 'type': 'FS'}
```

Expected result => the test case has to pass

actual result
pytest -c setup.cfg tests/test_fs_service.py

error is

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
__init__.py                 58 WARNING  Failed operation _store_result.  Retrying 0 more times.
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

how to mock self.update  in the fs_service.py 
how to mock db.create_all or create_db in conftest.py